# Dynamically create attr_accessor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am implementing an Advanced Search form in which I would like some fields to be added dynamically. I have a **Product** that `belongs_to` a **Pharmacy** that `belongs_to` a **Network**.

I want the user to be able to add more **Networks** to the form for example if he wants to search for **Products** from two different **Networks**.

Any tips on how I could dynamically create this field? In my mind I should implement some sort of `attr_accessor` that will be created as the user press a `+` in the view. But I don't think it is possible.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **should never create accessors based on user input**.

Instead you could add in your form array-like fields (i.e. `field[]`) or hash-like (i.e. `field[1]`)

Comment: Thanks! It was quite complicated for me but it was still the approach you said.